# How to access git local repository (in Centos) from jenkins which is running as container on same machine

Tags: git, jenkins

I have git local repository on Centos and jenkins as container on same machine. How to provide the git path in jenkins job to access it.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just access the file system of a host from inside of a container, that's partly the whole point of a container.

To some extent, running an app inside of a container (in this case Jenkins) is like running it on a separate host.

This means that in order to access a git repository on host A from Jenkins running inside a container on host A, you would need to expose that git repository in some way, usually via HTTP or SSH. You could do this following the [information given in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server). It might also require doing some configuration to set up networking between the container and host A.

But usually you would rather setup a dedicated Git server somewhere and use some kind software built on top of Git for that, for example [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com), which has a free and open source Community Edition.

Comment: 1. jenkins container

docker run --name Jenkins_Linux -d -p 9091:8080 jesusperales/jenkins-docker-run-inside

2. Bit bucket container 

docker volume create --name bitbucketVolume

docker run -v bitbucketVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket --name="bitbucket" -d -p 7990:7990 -p 7999:7999 atlassian/bitbucket-server

Both are up and running on same centos machine. How can I access the git path in jenkins job?